# Swift iOS - How To Print Result into A Specific Label/Image/etc

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, printing

Situation:

```
@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton)
...

if (x < 0)
   y = 0;
   let result = "Answer is \(y));
   print(result);
...
```

My `print(result)` is within an if statement within an IBAction. If I wanted to print this result on the screen. How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UILabel` in the storyboard and create an `IBOutlet` or create one programmatically and place it on the view to your ViewController. Then just set the text property ob the label to result. For example creating a label programatically:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        let myLabel: UILabel!
    
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
               myLabel = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
               myLabel.center = view.center
               view.addSubview(myLabel)
        }

@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton)
...

if (x < 0)
   y = 0;
   let result = "Answer is \(y))"
   print(result)
   myLabel.text = result
...
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify if I'm understanding this correctly? So I would create a `UILabel` in the storyboard, drag and drop in the code to create an `IBOutlet` and would that `IBOutlet` be within the `IBAction`? How would I print the result into the `UILabel` from the if statement? Do I just swap out `print(result);` to `myUILabel.text = result` in the same line? Thanks!!!

Comment: I've added some code to illustrate. But yes, add the IBOutlet, as long as its a property of your VC you'll have access to it from everywhere in your VC implementation.